# How to properly make a jasmine test for a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I recently started to use Jasmine for javascript testing, and I'm stuck with a problem. I'm sure someone here can help me.

I have the following simple code, posted on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/armino-dev/pen/RwNVJRW):

The HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="btnEraseDiv">Erase Div</button>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding:20px;
  background-color:#eef;
}

button{
  padding:10px 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color:#fdd;
}

#toBeErased{
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #ffdddd;
  background-color:#ffccdd;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

And the JavaScript:

```js
const eraseDiv = () => {
  const myDiv = $('#toBeErased');
  myDiv.children('p').fadeOut(300, () => {
    myDiv.fadeOut(600, () => {
      myDiv.remove();
    });
  })  
}

const addMyDiv = () => {
  const myDiv = $(`<div id="toBeErased">
    <p>This div and all its content will be erased. <br />Click the button bellow to erase it.</p>    
  </div>`);
  if (!document.querySelectorAll('#toBeErased').length) {
    $('div.container').append(myDiv);
  }
};


$(document).ready(() => {
  $('button#btnEraseDiv').on('click', () => {
    eraseDiv();
  });

});

//here starts the test

describe("Erase button functionality", () => {
  beforeEach( () => {
    addMyDiv();
  });

  it('should erase the div when btnEraseDiv clicked - using async', async () => {
    //this test here is the mistery
    const btn = $('button#btnEraseDiv');
    await btn.click();
    expect($('div#toBeErased').length).toBeLessThan(1);
  });

  it('should erase the div when btnEraseDiv clicked - using done and timeout', (done) => {
    //this is working, but i'm sure it is not the right usage
    const btn = $('button#btnEraseDiv');
    btn.click();    
    setTimeout( () => {
      expect($('div#toBeErased').length).toBeLessThan(1);
      done();
    }, 2000);
  });



});
```

Reading the documentation I have come out with this test which fails:

```js
it('should erase the div when btnEraseDiv clicked - using async', async () => {
    //this test here is the mistery
    const btn = $('button#btnEraseDiv');
    await btn.click();
    expect($('div#toBeErased').length).toBeLessThan(1);
  });
```

Then I make the other one with a timeout bigger than the fadeout durations and it works, but it feels improper.

```js
it('should erase the div when btnEraseDiv clicked - using done and timeout', (done) => {
    //this is working, but i'm sure it is not the right usage
    const btn = $('button#btnEraseDiv');
    btn.click();    
    setTimeout( () => {
      expect($('div#toBeErased').length).toBeLessThan(1);
      done();
    }, 2000);
  });
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or give me an example for this situation?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think your "improper" solution with the `done` param is actually a pretty good way to go. Your first solution with `async`/`await` doesn't quite work out because the jQuery `click()` method doesn't return an awaitable type (a Promise or "thenable").

If you'd rather have an `async`/`await` solution, here's something you could try:

```js
// Add a reusable utility method for your tests.
const wait = async ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

it('should erase the div when btnEraseDiv clicked - using async', async () => {
  $('button#btnEraseDiv').click();

  await wait(2000); // Wait for animations to complete.

  expect($('div#toBeErased').length).toBeLessThan(1);
});
```

**Side Note**

Another thing you may want to consider, especially if you're going to be writing and maintaining a lot of UI tests, is using an E2E/UI testing library like [Nightwatch](https://nightwatchjs.org/), [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer), Selenium, [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/), or [Protractor](https://www.protractortest.org/) (if you're using Angular).

These libraries will allow you to write tests that exist separate from your implementation code. You can run them in a normal browser or headless browser instance. They all have built in "driver" API functions that allow you to "wait" for certain DOM conditions. For instance `waitForElementPresent()` from Nightwatch or `waitForSelector()` from Puppeteer. There are many more API methods available to help you easily write maintainable E2E/UI tests.

Comment: Thanks allot, I will try the Nightwatch.